# Javascript: Is it possible to catch all form inputs and output it

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

Currently working on a Javascript script which needs to fetch all the input data at the moment a contact form is submittend on a website.

**Flow:**

1. Someone fill in a contact form
2. Form is processed with POST (php
   form)
3. Our script should fetch all the input fields + values on
   submit

Upfront we do not know the fields/id's of the contact forms.

**Question:**
Is it even possible to fetch this data (without knowing the fields in the form )?

Comment: Look into `serialize()` jquery method.

Comment: Do you want the JavaScript to find all entered values and then submit those values to the server for PHP? Because the way your 'flow' is written it seems like step 3 is in the wrong place, given that the data seems to have already been processed with PHP in step 2.

Comment: Answer to the question : Yes, it's possible to fetch that data without knowing the fields, just iterate over all the fields in the form *before* it's send to the server ?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? What is the goal?

Comment: Let me explain more, the form data which is handled by PHP is just 1 thing. Beside this, we want that this data is also fetch by Javascript, so we can use if for different purposes. So once a user press submit, the PHP post will be executed + the Javascript function.

Comment: And also should you be submitting unknown fields to your database for processing?

Comment: @Pointy we have many websites from our customers which are generating leads. We want to know catch all the data and store it in a dashboard on our side

Comment: Then you should probably store that in a database, and just output it in that "dashboard". Also, when you submit the form you can redirect to another page where the data is displayed, all without a single line of javascript.

Comment: We actually want to embedded this piece of Javascript like you embedded the Google Tracking code. So we can install it on all our customers websites and we can track the leadgeneration.

Comment: So basically you want to create a script that tracks users behaviour across multiple sites, and aggregates everything in a dashboard, and you don't even know how to submit a form? It's probably going to be a bit more complicated than just getting the values from a form.

Comment: @adeneo yes this is what we want. The websites already has contact forms. They only thing we need is an extra function in javascript that post that data to our end-point.

Answer (score 0):

Just make foreach for example

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  Echo $key . " = " . $value;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes , but this is PHP. We need client side (javascript).

Comment: Then you can fetch buy fetching your form fields $('#formId').serialize();

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai - wouldn't it be better if he looked at all the answers, not just yours ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery serializeArray method:

```
       $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost/user/form.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
```

Just select the form element with jQuery and call serializeArray.

Comment: If the OP was using jQuery (he might be, but it's not tagged in this question) then this answer might be relevant. As it is, it may not be; but that depends on the OP.